# Apply a modified camera profile when importing from a 5D-II to Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, canon-5d-mark-ii, presets

I am using a custom camera profile on my Canon 5D mkII where I bump saturation by one and decrease contrast by two. This is applied to JPEG files and not to the raw files which makes sense.

Is there a way to automatically apply the same modifications when I import raw files into Lightroom?

Comment: Lightroom supports per camera and per lens presets.  I do not know if it supports distinguishing between RAW and JPEG however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The in-camera contrast and saturation settings have no effect on a RAW file when opened in Lightroom.** The Lightroom profile you have selected determines how the image is displayed based on the RAW data. You could create a customized profile in Lightroom with increased saturation and decreased contrast that is applied every time a RAW file is opened from a specific camera or even a specific camera/lens combination, but the settings applied would come from the Lightroom profile and not the in-camera settings. **The same scene taken with the same ISO, shutter speed, and aperture and saved as RAW files will all appear identical when opened in Lightroom, regardless of what Picture Style and amounts of Contrast, Saturation, and so on were selected in-camera at the time each shot was taken.** The only way to see the difference in in-camera settings for things such as Contrast and Saturation with a RAW file is to open them with an application that reads and applies the in-camera settings when displaying the RAW file. One such program would be Canon's *Digital Photo Professional*.

Comment: Incidentally, one of the several things that are stripped from RAW .cr2 files when they are converted to Adobe .dng files because Adobe products ignore them anyway are the in-camera shooting settings for things like contrast, saturation, etc.

Comment: I am working on matching the in-camera profile when importing to LR. I am almost there but I still don't have the exact same picture though :) Thanks for the reply, that's the info I was looking for.

Comment: Since Adobe uses their own demosaicing algorithms (instead of Canon's) close is about all you can get when using LR. If all they need are global adjustments I process all of my RAW files using Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* so that they open with the in-camera settings applied. I can then export a 16-bit TIFF to LR or PS.