# Lightroom CC automatically adds "Adobe Default" preset to imported RAW photos

Tags: lightroom, raw, panasonic-lumix

I have noticed that on all my RAW pictures I import into Lightroom CC the software automatically applies the "Adobe Default" preset. Is there a way to change this behaviour so it sticks with the "Camera Settings" preset?

Comment: My LR CC 9.4 set (for Canon RAW) Camera Standard colour profile. Do you have any import presets set?

Comment: Related: [How to automatically apply a Lightroom Preset based on appropriate (Canon) Picture Style on import](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48431/15871) and [How do I start with in-camera JPEG settings in Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13924/15871) and [Apply a modified camera profile when importing from a 5D-II to Lightroom](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45540/15871)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start with in-camera JPEG settings in Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/how-do-i-start-with-in-camera-jpeg-settings-in-lightroom)

Comment: @MichaelC: Thank you but no. I am not using any fancy camera profiles or anything, I am shooting fully manual in RAW.

Comment: @Haris Your camera still assigns color profiles to the EXIF info, based upon its analysis of the scene or upon your manual CT and WB settings - which Adobe is mostly ignoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction:

With the last release of LR (June 2020) there is a "Camera Preset" develop preset, which is a camera matching color profile; and in some cases it will pick up some basic/detail adjustments as well (e.g. saturation/sharpening). With my Nikon's, all it does is change the color profile to "Camera Neutral" and all other settings to Adobe defaults.

An option that is probably better is to edit an image with basic/generic edits; setting the color profile, saturation, sharpening, noise reduction, etc, to your desired/typical starting point for most images. Then go to the develop menu > new preset > save with unique name. Now you can apply that profile (or any other) by default by setting it in the preset preferences; either by camera model as I have done (with override selected), or by changing the Master preset.

As shown in the image you can also make an adaptive ISO preset by editing a high ISO image, and a low ISO image; and then selecting them both before selecting the new preset menu option. I use an Adaptive ISO preset, but I have switched one to the Camera Settings preset for the screen capture.

[image]

https://blog.thomasfitzgeraldphotography.com/blog/2020/6/creating-iso-adaptive-presets-in-lightroom-93

Comment: Is it not true that a RAW file is just data and therefor if any settings, camera or otherwise, are applied then it is no long a RAW file.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, the edits in LR do not actually change the raw data until the image is exported. With LR the edits/settings applied are more of a "preview" of what the data will look like when eventually exported; the edits/settings are saved in a separate database.

Comment: I understand that. My Adobe , Bridge, Camera Raw do the same.  The text read "Apply camera settings", that infers not just for viewing purposes but applying. I was just trying to call attention to the use of words  and have them match the intended meaning.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, except that LR doesn't automatically *apply* settings in that manner.

Comment: I checked again and I was slightly mistaken. It is not the colour profile that is automatically selected but a preset that is getting applied automatically. Lightroom uses the "Adobe Default" preset when I import pictures, but the "Camera Settings" preset is the one that is actually closest to the image I saw in the EVF.

Comment: @Haris, I guess I was wrong too... I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AlaskaMan That's true. It's also true that the 'just data" in a raw file is not displayable on any monitor. A profile of some sort has to be used to convert that data to a viewable image.

Comment: Edits in LR don't really change the raw data even when the image is exported. What is exported is not the raw data, it's an interpretation of that raw data using a particular instruction set on how to process that data to arrive at a raster image.