# Mirror the settings of Sony's JPEG generation on the RAW (*.arw) file opened in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, sony-alpha

Sometimes, I'm perfectly happy with the JPG generated by my Sony Alpha 6100, but want to rotate the image a bit in Lightroom. To not cause increased loss due to recompression, I would naturally prefer to apply the rotation on the RAW (*.arw) file. However, that would mean I now need to carefully re-construct the color balance, tone curves etc. to match the JPG, an issue that's also [touched in this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41327/why-do-raw-images-look-worse-than-jpegs-in-editing-programs).

**Is there a way for Lightroom (or another app) to automatically glean the settings which Sony applied and use them as basis?** Sort of the color equivalent of the Lightroom lens correction feature, which seems to take its info from such things as camera model, aperture etc., for great results. Thanks!

Comment: Do Sony make their own 'pro/RAW' photo app at all? That would be my choice, based on similar issues on Nikon cameras. Use the native app, export as TIFF, edit in Adobe. Native corrections carried with no additional decoding required.

Comment: see this answer: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119535/lightroom-cc-automatically-adds-adobe-default-preset-to-imported-raw-photos/119536#119536

Comment: @StevenKersting That sounds great, will try and report back. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start with in-camera JPEG settings in Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/how-do-i-start-with-in-camera-jpeg-settings-in-lightroom)

Answer (score 1):

The only way (I know) to get close to the camera's JPEG is to use [Imaging Edge Desktop](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/) from Sony itself.

Download software for your OS, install it, go to Edit, Adjusting Images, find [Creative Style/Creative Look](https://support.d-imaging.sony.co.jp/app/imagingedge/en/instruction/3_3_retouching.php) and there select the style you use in your camera when take photo(s).

For lens correction search for Lens Correction in the same place.